# Is Superclass's constructor run inside child constructor in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

If I have this class:

```
<?php
class Model
{
    var $db;

    function Model()
    {
        $this->db=new Db_Class();
    }
}
?>
```

and a second class that extended the parent class:

```
<?php
class LessonModel extends Model
{

    public function LessonModel()
    {
        //code here
    }

    public function getTitle($id)
    {
       $this->db->setTable('myTable');
       return $this->db->get('title',$id);
    }
}
?>
```

Is it safe to assume that the `$LessonModel->db` field would have been instantiated by the parent `Model` class's constructor, or do I need to run it manually using something like `parent::Model();`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot assume that the parent constructor has been called because you have overridden this in your subclass. You would need to call `parent::Model()` as you suggest. If you change the class you are inheriting from you would obviously need to change this.

If you are using PHP5 then you can name your constructors `__construct()`. This has the benefit of letting you easily call a parent constructor by doing `parent::__construct()` in any derived class without specifying the parent class name. You can then rearrange your classes' inheritance with less hassle and less danger of introducing obscure bugs.

Answer (score 0):

In the given example, you can assume that.

However, if your child class defines a constructor, PHP will not implicitly call it's parent constructor.

In order to do that, call:

```
parent::__construct();
```

Comment: His child class has defined a constructor using the older naming convention Classname()

Comment: Seriously the more I program on PHP the more I hate it! What the hell! I have almost the same class structure as the given example. I'm using the code for database connection. According to what I've seen here I have to initialize a new connection every time I need to do a query ?! I'm totally starting to think changing to Java! @Click Upvote Yeah... :/

Answer (score 0):

There's a cheap way to get around having to call the parent constructor.

Create an empty init() method in the base class.  Call $this->init() in the base class constructor.

All sub-classes can implement init() if they want to run code when the class is created.