# Can I force a child class to use the parent's constructor?

Tags: php, inheritance, constructor

I'm learning PHP and found some surprising behaviour when I was trying to figure out why a constructor wasn't getting called.

```
<?php
    class Shape {

        function __construct() { 
            echo 'Shape.';
        }
    }

    class Triangle extends Shape {

        function __construct() {        
            echo 'Triangle';
        }
    }

    $tri = new Triangle();
?>
```

I'm used to java, so I thought this would output "Shape. Triangle."  Surprisingly, it just outputs "Triangle."  I searched for the problem and apparently I can kinda sorta fix it by putting `parent::__construct();` in the child class, but that doesn't seem ideal.  Is there anything I can do to the Shape class to ensure that child classes always call the parent constructor?  Do I really have to write `parent::__construct();` in the class of every child whenever the parent has a constructor?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to, unless you don't define the child constructor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Superclass's constructor run inside child constructor in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738571/is-superclasss-constructor-run-inside-child-constructor-in-php)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you define a method of the same name in a child class, the parent's method is overridden and will not be called under any circumstances, unless you do so explicitly. I.e.: No, there's nothing you can do about it, you have to call `parent::__construct()` explictly.

Comment: You could also have the parent declare an abstract or empty initialize method that the parent constructor calls.

Comment: @erisco That would be a good design pattern to work around this, but it doesn't change the facts. :)

Comment: @deceze The initial question does ask about emulating a specific behavior... which can, in fact, be emulated.

Comment: @Mirrored I wouldn't say that using `final` and designating another method as the constructor is a great alternative. What if you want to extend the extending class and ensure *its* alternative constructor is run? It's not a very scalable solution. The default PHP idiom is to use `parent`. It's every developer's decision and responsibility to do so.

Comment: @deceze I wouldn't say it's a "great" alternative, either, and probably not suitable for most situations. But it is incorrect to say "there's nothing you can do about it"

Answer (score 15):

As of PHP 5, you can use the [final keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) to prevent a parent method from being overridden.

```
<?php
class BaseClass {
   public function test() {
       echo "BaseClass::test() called\n";
   }

   final public function moreTesting() {
       echo "BaseClass::moreTesting() called\n";
   }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
   public function moreTesting() {
       echo "ChildClass::moreTesting() called\n";
   }
}
// Results in Fatal error: Cannot override final method BaseClass::moreTesting()
```

You could use this in combination with a pre-defined `init()` method to ensure your parent constructor was called.

```
<?php
abstract class Shape {

    final function __construct() { 
        $this->init();
        echo 'Shape.';
    }

    abstract public function init();
}

class Triangle extends Shape {

    function init() {        
        echo 'Triangle';
    }
}

$tri = new Triangle();
```

This would output

```
TriangleShape.
```

It is advisable to only use a design like this if you document what the `init()` method does, and where it is called in the parent.

Answer (score 2):

According to the PHP manual:

```
Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class defines
a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to
parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required.
```